# Database Authorised Updates

Tags: mysql, database-design, authorization, roles

How do I design a database structure so that a number of user of a database can add, update and delete records which may include foreign keys from some of the database's tables and prevent these changes from going live until the user's supervisor authorises these changes, some of these changes or declines these changes from occuring. The database will eventualy have a number of these groups of users and supervisors.

What is the best methodology, or system for this, I am using MySQL database at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views.

All access to "live" data should be through views. The views should select only only those rows that have been "authorized". You'll want to manage permissions (SQL GRANT and REVOKE statements) so application code can't bypass the views by going directly to the tables.

This might not be obvious, but that means that all the user interface code needs to go to the views, too. For example, most user interfaces will ease the burden of picking the right foreign key by loading a combo box or list box, popping up a modal dialog, or something along those lines. Those interface elements need to get their data from views of "authorized" rows, too.